# is it possibile to split column value info multipe rows with the same content in other columns?

Tags: filter, powerbi

I would like to get a new table based on another with unique values for Anna and Marcin or the number of colors for each name. Is it possible?

Sample data on powerbi

| Name | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Anna | yellow |
| Marcin, Anna | orange |

As a result, I would like to get

| Name | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Anna | yellow |
| Marcin | orange |
| Anna | orange |

or

| Name | Color Count |
| --- | --- |
| Anna | 2 |
| Marcin | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Just use this simple option while split and done.

[image]

And here is the output- (**Apply trim to remove white space from the output**)

[image]